# AMD R9 280X | Programm/Pc crash/freezes until reaching a specific temperature

Tags: graphics-card, freeze, gpu, amd-radeon, temperature

I have an R9 280X from Asus which always produce some issues if its get too hot.
Some data from tests:
PC1 (I7 6700k, 650W Corsair PSU, 16GB Ram, Win10)
[list]
[*] Witcher 3 crashed at 76 C°
[*] GW2 crashed always at 74 C°
[*] Fortnite freezes always at 74 C°
[*] The Crew freezes always at 74 C°
[/list]

PC2 (AMD FX 8320 8xCore, Thermaltake 630W PSU, 8GB Ram, Win7)
FurMark first freeze at 64 C°, lose display driver and display turn off and on. 
If I start FurMark with the same situation again, everything freeze and I have to reset manually.

I tested it on 2 completely different systems if the same drivers (18.12.1) and get very similar problems.

If I turn the clock down (from the standard clock) and turn the RPM to 50% I can handle most games (with lower video settings) under 70C° and it all games run stable nothing crashes 
But this isn't the solution.
I never used AMD GPUs before is there any "safety option" so it turns automatically off at high temperature (even 74 C° isn't really high)?
Or are the AMD Cards really so temperature sensitive?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Have you considered there is just something wrong with the card? RMA it. At this point I’d buy a different card all together just to make sure it’s not some compatibility issue.

Comment: Yes i know there is something wrong with the card. But if I would always buy everything new I would get poor.
And its only a card to wait for the new GeForce series because my old 770 broked completely.

Comment: This is a video card issue, something in the cooling system of the card has failed... The fan isn't working, the bond of the heatsinks to the chips has opened up, thermal paste incorrect, etc. or something related to that. Can you correct it? Maybe, but the heat may have actually caused damage to the components or connections on the video card itself. At this point with the information given any answer would be purely speculation.

Comment: I cleaned the card, replaced the thermal paste, checked the fans everything is ok I think.
what really could be is, that the card was at high temperature before I get it. I don't know what was done with it before.
Maybe you are right that the hight temperature damaged the components earlier.